# Which SE site is best for a question involving restoring arcade machines?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I’m working on restoring a classic Space Invaders cocktail-table arcade game. I have questions that are electrical in nature, questions that are mechanical in nature, as well as others.

First and foremost, I have a question regarding replacing the coin acceptor and determining whether the machine provides 12V or 5V to the existing coin acceptor. The manuals I have found online haven’t been much help in that regard, and the schematics I’ve found are just gibberish to me. I’m hoping the community might have some users who are knowledgeable about arcade electronics and could offer me a suggestion such as *“here are good places to attach a voltmeter to get that info.”*

What’s the appropriate SE site for such questions?

Answer (score 7):

> I have a question regarding replacing the coin acceptor and determining whether the machine provides 12V or 5V to the existing coin acceptor.

For this kind of problem [electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is certainly the right place.

> the manuals I have found online haven’t been much help in that regard, and the schematics I’ve found are just gibberish to me. (...) “here are good places to attach a voltmeter to get that info.”

Ibidem. You might need to reverse-engineer your own diagrams in which case [reverseengineering.stackexchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) together with [electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) should cover most of your practical and methodological needs.

> questions that are mechanical in nature

Some electromechanical machines pose indeed an interdisciplinary problem. The may be on-topic in the above sites. If not, the mechanical part of the question can also be asked on [engineering.stackexchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com) see the [Mechanical engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tags/mechanical-engineering/info#) tag for some guidance.

Answer (score 6):

At least some of your questions should be on-topic at [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @PeteHooper Based on the topic you mentioned in your question (mostly electro-mechanical ones), I think your questions might fall just *barely* outside the scope of RC. I don’t think it would hurt to ask, though.

Comment: Thanks. Figure I’ll take a look there and get an idea of whether it fits. Appreciate the feedback.